# Flattening xml data in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I'm trying to flatten XML data in a SQL query but I always seem to get nulls.

I tried the cross/outer apply method described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/simonince/2009/04/24/flattening-xml-data-in-sql-server/).

The column with XML data is called `Data`.

I'm guessing that the xml data with these links need to be somehow also added?

Could you please help to get a proper SQL query?

Query I tried:

```
SELECT
 v.name
 ,pref.value('(LocalId/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(10)') as localid
FROM [database].[requests] v
outer apply v.Data.nodes('/DataForm') x(pref)
GO
```

example of xml data in that column:

```
  <Dataform xmlns="http://somelongasslink.org/hasalsosomestuffhere" xmlns:i="http://somexlmschemalink/">
    <DeleteDate xmlns="http://somelongasslink.org/hasalsosomestuffhere" i:nil="true" />
    <LocalId xmlns="http://somelongasslink.org/hasalsosomestuffhere">5325325</LocalId>
  ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code to get the result you're looking for:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://somelongasslink.org/hasalsosomestuffhere')
SELECT
    rq.Name,
    LocalID = TC.value('(LocalId)[1]', 'nvarchar(10)') 
FROM 
     [database].[requests] rq
CROSS APPLY
    rq.Data.nodes('/Dataform') AS TX(TC)
GO
```

There were two problems with your code:

1. you're not respecting / including the **XML namespace** that's defined on the XML document

   ```
   <Dataform xmlns="http://somelongasslink.org/hasalsosomestuffhere" 
             *******************************************************
   ```
2. you didn't pay attention to the **case-sensitivity** of XML in your call to `.nodes()` - you need to use `.nodes('/Dataform')` (not `/DataForm` - the `F` is *not* capitalized in your XML)

Comment: You might need to define the namespace "xmlns:i" too, if you explicitly want to read the `i:nil` attribute... Upvote from my side

Comment: How to deal when there are multiple namespaces ? The code you provided works (thanks for that) but for other attributes without namespaces.
My example xml is a bit incorrect to my case as the link namespace at localid is different then at dataform.

Comment: @Exanimis: you would have to use `WITH XMLNAMESPACES('.....' AS ns1, '.......' AS ns2)` and then use those prefixes defined in the XPath expressions

Comment: found it but still have some problems how to type those prefixes in that query:
 LocalID = TC.value('(LocalId)[1]', 'nvarchar(10)') 
 and in rq.Data.nodes('/Dataform') AS TX(TC)

Comment: Oh i got it now i type LocalID = TC.value('(/ns1:Dataform/ns2:LocalId)[1]', 'nvarchar(10)'), and works thanks for your help !